# ValueError: option error in Django / Python

Tags: python, django, ldap, python-ldap

I'm building a django website and trying to implement LDAP to it.

Whenever I call `ldap.set_option()`, I get this error:

```
ValueError: option error
```

Any idea why this is happening?

This is the [document](http://packages.python.org/django-auth-ldap/) I'm following.

Thanks for looking into this and greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

http://packages.python.org/django-auth-ldap/#auth-ldap-global-options

Is `AUTH_LDAP_GLOBAL_OPTIONS` defined and does it have items in it?

Perhaps it is not defined?

Comment: This is how i have it and still getting the error: 

ldap_cert_path = '/apps/essweb/qa_ldap.cert'
AUTH_LDAP_GLOBAL_OPTIONS = {
        ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE: False,
}

ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE,ldap_cert_path)

Comment: Also...above is in settings.py

And added 'GLOBAL_OPTIONS': {}, under 'class LDAPSettings(object):' in 'django_auth_ldap/backend.py'.

Comment: This is the error i'm seeing on my browser.

Any help is appreciated!

ValueError at /admin/

option error

Request Method:  POST
Request URL:          http://0.0.0.0:8080/admin/
Django Version:  1.4
Exception Type:  ValueError
Exception Value:  option error

Exception Location:  /apps/thhweb/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/python_ldap-2.4.10-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/ldap/functions.py in _ldap_function_call, line 63
Python Executable:  /apps/essweb/python/bin/python
Python Version:  2.6.