# Python LDAP ValueError: option error when using set_option(ldap. OPT_X_TLS_CACERTDIR)

Tags: python, django, openldap, pyldap

I'm using the django authentication backend [django-auth-ldap](https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/) to authenticate against an LDAP service. When attempting to set the path to the directory containing the ssl certificate;

```
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CACERTDIR, '/etc/ssl/certs')
```

I get a ValueError exception:

```
File "/Users/liz/web_application/work/ldap_settings.py", line 5, in <module>
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CACERTDIR, '/etc/ssl/certs')

File "/Users/liz/.envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ldap/functions.py", line 139, in set_option
return _ldap_function_call(None,_ldap.set_option,option,invalue)

File "/Users/liz/.envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ldap/functions.py", line 66, in _ldap_function_call
result = func(*args,**kwargs)

ValueError: option error
```

I've tried the accepted answer from this [previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328378/python-ldap-macos-valueerror-option-error) that suggests uninstalling python-ldap (though I'm using [pyldap](https://github.com/pyldap/pyldap), a fork of python-ldap) and re-installing using a brew-installed openldap by running:

```
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/brew/opt/openldap/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/brew/opt/openldap/include" pip install python-ldap
```

This seemed to have no effect. I also followed [this guide](https://keathmilligan.net/python-ldap-and-macos/), to locally build a version of pyldap with the newer version of openldap (via brew), but I still see the same error. I'm not sure if there's some way I can verify my local build does use the newer openldap library, or if there's something I'm missing here? Any suggestions are much appreciated!

**Other existing questions on SO**

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617147/valueerror-option-error-in-django-python) has no effect for me; setting AUTH_LDAP_GLOBAL_OPTIONS instead of set_option results in the same ValueError

```
AUTH_LDAP_GLOBAL_OPTIONS = {ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CACERTDIR: '/etc/ssl/certs'}
```

Comment: Check permissions for that folder. Can Django access it?

Comment: Yes, folder and contents are readable for all

Comment: I've traced it down and all it does is copy the given path to the option structure, but only if TLS is available in libldap. So there does seem to be a disconnect between python module and libldap. Could you show output of `ldd /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_ldap.so`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have some work about LDAP. So Ill provide my code for you if that helps you. First I put cert into django procject.

```
BASE_DIR = Djando base dir

def returnPaths():
    return     {'dn_full_path': 'CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=your_con,DC=your_dc,DC=your_dc',
                'cert': 'path_to_cert_file',
                'host': 'ldaps://x.x.x.:636'
                }

class LdapBackend(object):
    @classmethod
    def authenticate(cls, username=None, password=None):

        try:
            setup = returnPaths()

            ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER)
            ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE, BASE_DIR + setup['cert'])

            domain = 'your_doman'
            l = ldap.initialize(setup['host'])
            l.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
            l.set_option(ldap.OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)
            l.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_DEMAND)
            l.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_DEMAND, True)

            try:
                l.simple_bind_s('%s@%s' % (str(username.encode('utf-8')), domain),
                                password.encode('utf-8'))
                return True
            except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS as e:
                return False
            except Exception as e:
                return False
        except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS as e:
            return False
```